# Possible to change serif for parts of letters?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

I was wondering if it is possible to adjust the font family for text.  What I mean by this is times new roman has small lines (serif) on the entire letter.  Is it possible to put serif on only the top of the letters.  It doesn't seem like this is possible, but I thought I saw it somewhere.  Here is my code if it is possible...

```
<style type="text/css">
p.pnc{font-size:8em; padding-top:0px; margin-top:-385px; margin-left:250px; color:#0054A8; font-family:arial;}
</style>        

</head>

<body>

<div id="sample-2" style=" background-color:#F0F0F0; width:1000px; height:500px;">
</div>
<div>
<p class="pnc">PNC</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'd have to find and use an alternate font.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Just making sure.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't (reasonably) do that with JavaScript; it would require rendering the top with a serif font and the bottom with a sans-serif font, and unless designed to be used in that way, the result would likely be unreadable (or at least very unattractive).

You could create a [web font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography), of course, that only has serifs where you want them. Or you might find a web font out there that has essentially the look you want already, there are thousands (for instance, [here](http://www.google.com/webfonts/))...

Comment: That's what i thought.  Thank you.